# Create a homepage like Wordpress.com?

Tags: multisite

How can I create a homepage like Wordpress.com. I am currently using wordpress MS and would like to display the latest posts across the network on the homepage. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This theme sort of does the same thing http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/goodtheme-lead

Answer (score -1):

At the moment, there is really no way of doing this for Multisite so that your main network page looks like WordPress.com. Unless you are experienced with theme development and PHP, in which case you could make a theme with only index.php and a couple other files that almost does away with the loop, you are out of luck.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to tell us?